# Cannot create a row of size 11616 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060. When using dynamic SQL to create dynamic columns

Tags: sql, azure, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

```
-- Generate dynamic column list
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Attribute) 
                   FROM AttributeValue 
                   WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectId
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

-- Define data types for the columns
DECLARE @columnDefinitions NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columnDefinitions = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Attribute) + ' NVARCHAR(100)' 
                                FROM AttributeValue 
                                WHERE ProjectID = @ProjectId
                                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

SET @createTableQuery = 'CREATE TABLE ##Attributes (AssetItemID INT, ' + @columnDefinitions + ');';
SET @query = 'INSERT INTO ##Attributes
                  SELECT AssetItemID, ' + @cols + '
                  FROM 
                      (SELECT i.AssetItemID, av.Attribute, i.Value
                       FROM Item2Item i
                       INNER JOIN AttributeValue av ON av.AttributeValueID = i.SubTypeAttributeID
                       INNER JOIN AssetItem (NOLOCK) a ON a.AssetItemID = i.AssetItemID
                       WHERE av.ProjectID = ' +CAST(@ProjectId AS VARCHAR(10))+'
                         AND a.Owner = '+ QUOTENAME(@Package,'''') +' 
                    ) src
                    PIVOT (
                        MAX(Value) FOR [Attribute] IN (' + @cols + ')
                    ) AS piv;';`
```

I have tried setting `columnDefinitions` when defining the columns to even `NVARCHAR(1)` and doesn't work have around 450 attributes but still states row size to big

Comment: Why do you need a temp table anyway? Why not just `SELECT` straight out of the dynamic SQL? Also if you are using Azure why use the old `FOR XML` aggregation, why not `STRING_AGG`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem that you are having usually happens when the combined size of your columns exceeds the SQL Server row size limit. In your case, having around 450 attributes with `NVARCHAR(100)` each contributes to this.

To make this right, try reducing the column size, maybe to `NVARCHAR(50)`, to shrink the overall row size. else you can do vertical partitioning, like breaking your table into smaller ones with fewer columns.

Comment: have tried even NVARCHAR(1) still states that it is over the row size limit
it is stored between different tables but need to create this template for download

Comment: sorry mate, try vertical partinoning might work

Comment: fixed it needed to set a NVARCHAR to value column when pivioting not just when creating the table

Comment: awesome, thanks for letting know